# Eth Not add in my meta mask from test ether faucet?

Tags: ether, metamask, faucets

For the first time i am using meta mask and test ether faucet.and I want to add some test eth in my meta mask from test ether faucet but eth are not add In my meta mask.?

Comment: are you connected to right network with metamask?

Comment: Faucet regularly run out of ether, try again later or search for a different one, or perhaps switch to another test network like rinkeby or goerli.